# Why does initializing a struct need to use 4 levels of braces? I do not understand it

Tags: gcc

Could anyone help to answer why initializing this struct with null needs to use 4 braces?

struct scsi_transport_template blank_transport_template = { { { { NULL, }, }, }, };

```
struct scsi_transport_template {
    struct transport_container host_attrs;
    struct transport_container target_attrs;
    struct transport_container device_attrs;
    int (*user_scan)(struct Scsi_Host *, uint, uint, uint);
    int device_size;
    int device_private_offset;
    int target_size;
    int target_private_offset;
    int host_size;
    unsigned int create_work_queue : 1;
    void (* eh_strategy_handler)(struct Scsi_Host *);
    enum blk_eh_timer_return (*eh_timed_out)(struct scsi_cmnd *);
    int (* it_nexus_response)(struct Scsi_Host *, u64, int);
    int (* tsk_mgmt_response)(struct Scsi_Host *, u64, u64, int);
};
```

Comment: `struct scsi_transport_template blank_transport_template = {0};` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**1st** brace is for **scsi_transport_template** structure,

**2nd** brace is for **transport_container** structure,

**3rd** brace is for **attribute_container** structure,

**4th** brace is for **list_head** structure